# HP UFT override Checkpoint creation behavior

Tags: frameworks, automation, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I am currently working to create a framework for UFT test automation. 
I implemented a function *fct_ValidateCheckPoint* that verifies if a standard checkpoint exists, and write error in the log report if not.

I need, when creating a checkpoint (F12) , to **intercept** the UFT default behavior and **call** this function "*fct_ValidateCheckPoint*".

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I think there is no way (API, or other feature) to catch a checkpoint creation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve. During a checkpoint execution (`obj.Check`) the test verifies that the checkpoint object exists and fails the test if it does not.

During checkpoint creation, the checkpoint doesn't yet exist.

You should note that there are several ways to create checkpoints in UFT (not just <kbd>F12</kbd>), in any case UFT does not expose a way to override its built in checkpoint mechanism. You can always add functions that perform verification and then fail or pass the test explicitly.

Comment: What i need to do is : on the creation of the checkpoint, i need to call my method "fct_ValidateCheckPoint" automatically . I am assuming  that a non-technical user is working with UFT. I m doing my best so no user have to modify the UFT generated code (as i said this method check the existence of a checkpoint and write in the log report)